# gsub: replacing apostrophe with double apostrophe in a string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I want to replace all apostrophe (straight single quote) with double apostrophe in a string in my shell script.
I used the following gsub command:

```
gsub(/'/, "''", string);
```

But I got an error because I need to insert a second straight single quote to match with the first one. If I try to replace another part of the string it works just fine.

Comment: What if input text already has `''` (double single quotes) in it?

Comment: Well, it doesn't and this is not the case here.

Comment: Removing the single quote is also an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
s="jonn's and smith's band"
awk '{gsub(/\047/, "\047\047")} 1' <<< "$s"

jonn''s and smith''s band
```

`047` represents octal code for single quote character `'`.

Comment: I tried and I got an error. I forgot to mention that I am trying to do this in an awk script and I am not sure if awk can be an awk command.

Comment: I just used \047 insted of straight single quote and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The right way to do this is to just replace any literal `'`(s) with the octal code for it `\047`:

```
$ echo "foo'bar" | awk '{gsub(/\047/,"&&")}1'
foo''bar
```

That's the right approach as it'll work in or out of a script file and will will work inside a regexp literal (unlike using a variable to hold the quote character which would force you to use a dynamic regexp with the additional complexity that requires for some cases).

Also - do not be tempted to use the hex code `\x27` instead of the octal `\047` as the hex doesn't always behave as expected, see http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

${string//\"/\'} negating the need to use awk all together.